# k6 - can't import function from another file - moduleSpecifier couldn't be found on local disk

Tags: javascript, typescript, k6

Here is a test file where I import a function from another file

> tests/signup.ts

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep, check } from 'k6';
import { getCloudflareToken } from '../GoogleCloud';

export default async function () {
  const email = test@email.com;
  const cf_token = await getCloudflareToken('development');
```

I keep getting this error even though I'm importing correctly:

```
ERRO[0000] GoError: The moduleSpecifier "../GoogleCloud" couldn't be found on local disk. Make sure that you've specified the right path to the file.
```

This is the GoogleCloud.ts file located in the root:

```
// Import the Secret Manager client and instantiate it:
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();


export async function getCloudflareToken(env: string) { 
  const projectID = env === "development" ? "123" : "456";
  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({ name: `projects/${projectID}/secrets/CF_TOKEN/versions/1` });
  if (version.payload && version.payload.data) {
    return version.payload.data.toString();
  } else {
    throw new Error("Payload data is missing or undefined.");
  }
}
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "load-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "unauthenticated-users.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "sign-up": "k6 run tests/sign-up.ts",
    "unauthenticated-users": "k6 run --vus 100 --duration 5m tests/unauthenticated-users.ts"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/k6": "^0.45.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.8",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you leave out the file extension when importing the file? The file name is `GoogleCloud.ts` (as explained by you in the next line) and not `GoogleCloud`.

Comment: @knittl Because its not required, with that now I have to change tsconfig. Ok now it runs but I just get different error instead: ```Unexpected token, expected , (6:44)
  4 | 
  5 | 
> 6 | export async function getCloudflareToken(env: string) {```

Comment: Actually option for .ts import doesn't exist anymore in ```tsconfig```, so the project can't compile. Back to square one.

Comment: It looks like you are not transpiling your TS to JS and trying to execute the TS directly. k6 cannot run TS directly, k6 can only execute JS (it uses a JS runtime written in Go: goja). https://github.com/grafana/k6-template-typescript

Comment: Ok, thanks. Weird I was able to get tests to run before though minus the import statement.

Comment: Well, TS almost looks like JS (plus the typing). If you change `env:string` to `env`, your code becomes valid JS and can be executed by k6